# What is the control name

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When creating new slide in powerpoint, it will always have "Click to add title" and "Click to add text" portions.

Sometimes I deleted them, if I wish to add them back, what control should I choose? (They don't seem like textboxes).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Create a new slide, select & cut the text box(from the newly created slide), then past it onto the desired slide.
2. If you deleted it then want it back (if you haven't done anything else), hit undo.
3. Create a new text box and add the desired styling.

Answer (score 0):

On the Home tab, Slides group, click RESET